# Oracle trying to update a column

Tags: oracle

I have a table containing some billion records and just need to update a single field with no condition.

`update <table name> set flag='N'` this is my update query, it takes a very long long time.
How to make this execute fast.

Comment: use indexing first then execute the updation!

Comment: Asha has no condition, so indexing the table won't help. Besides that, creating the index will probably take longer than the update anyway.

Comment: @Asha: You will probably have to live with it...

Comment: Indexes are a performance drag when the time comes to modify records.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* cannot wait that long to run your update, and can live with the flag being null instead of 'N', then you can do this very quickly (untested, but should work):

```
alter table my_tab set unused column flag;

alter table my_tab add (flag char(1));
```

You can later drop unused with checkpoints if you care to reclaim some space (note that the drop will take some time, so be careful if you choose to do this).

Hope that helps

EDIT: Thanks to @TTT for this [article](http://oracletoday.blogspot.nl/2007/10/fasttrue-for-adding-columns-in-11g.html), apparently in 11g Oracle can store a default value in the data dictionary rather than performing an update to all rows (what I expected from previous experiences).  This means you can use 'N' value instead of NULL.  *Just make sure you specify NOT NULL as well as the default value*:

```
SQL> set timing on
SQL> drop table test1
Table dropped.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.23

SQL> create table test1
(
col1 varchar2(10),
flag char(1)
)
Table created.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.14

SQL> insert into test1
select 'x','Y'
from dual
connect by level <= 1000000
1000000 rows created.
Elapsed: 00:00:02.09

SQL> alter table test1 set unused column flag
Table altered.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.07

SQL> alter table test1 add (flag char(1) default 'N' not null )
Table altered.
Elapsed: 00:00:01.01
```

Without the "NOT NULL" and just a default, it took over 20 secs, showing this "fast=true" trick only works when specifying not null and a default (which makes sense really).

Comment: I think that you can add a not null column with a default value without having to wait minutes or hours. It should take only 1 second or so. Read here: http://oracletoday.blogspot.nl/2007/10/fasttrue-for-adding-columns-in-11g.html

Comment: @TTT Thanks for the link.  I think the default of 'N' would take some time for a billion rows, but I could be wrong (perhaps 11g handles differently).

Comment: @TTT Thanks again, article is very interesting.  I'll do a quick test and update my answer with a default value if 11g really does NOT need to do the update with defaults!

Answer (score 0):

Do not update. Use CTAS, and then rename the new table.

```
CREATE TABLE T_NEW NOLOGGING PARALLEL AS
SELECT COL1, COL2, 'N' FLAG FROM T_OLD;
```

**Then apply indexes, constraints or grants from your old table.** If you forget this step you will suffer.

```
DROP TABLE_T_OLD;
RENAME T_NEW TO T_OLD;
```

*Try to be careful since you're dropping the old table.*

Answer (score 0):

**First ideea:**
If you have space:

```
  create table tmp_tab as select col1, ..., coln, "N" as flag 
  from your_tab; 

  rename table your_tab to your_tab_old; 

  rename tmp_tab to your_tab;
```

will very fast compared to simple update.

Drop your_tab_old if everything is ok.

**Second ideea:**

`update /*+parallel(your_tab 8)*/ your_tab set flag='N';`

will be
   faster than noparallel version.